# Getting started with BDD and nSpec

Tags: c#, bdd

In a previous question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359327/atdd-versus-bdd-and-the-proper-use-of-a-framework), I asked a question about BDD and SpecFlow.  The best answer was to use nSpec instead of SpecFlow.

I found nSpec, but I am having trouble finding tutorials on how to use it with C#.  My google mojo isn't working for this topic.

Apart from the small instructional on the nSpec github site on how to install nSpec, does anyone have any links to good beginning tutorials on using nSpec?

Comment: I think you mean nStep, not nSpec. NSpec's documentation/tutorials are still growing up. But there's lots of examples at http://nspec.org

Comment: Ya, kinda weird how the only official documentation is all smooshed onto the front page of the site, and there's not as much as you'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if we are talking about the same framework (whether you meant nStep or NSpec).  But here is some information on NSpec.

#### NSpec Project Site

There is an [NSpec Project Site](http://nspec.org) that has a good set of features showcased to help you get started.

#### Sample NSpec Usage

On github, the [NSpec Samples Project](https://github.com/mattflo/NSpec/tree/master/SampleSpecs) will give you greater insight into the framework.

#### Additional Resources

It's important to be aware that there are two flavors of BDD.  The following link explains the two different forms, their pros and cons, and how you can benefit from each:

- [What is the most mature BDD Framework for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307895/what-is-the-most-mature-bdd-framework-for-net/5586525#5586525)
- [NSpec Project Site](http://nspec.org)
- [Continuous Testing](http://www.nspec.org/continuoustesting)
- [Introduction to BDD and Mocking](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/introduction-to-behavior-driven-development-and-mocking)
- [BDD using NUnit and Moq](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/behavior-driven-development-in-dot-net-using-nunit-and-moq)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Cuke4nuke (nStep's cousin) screen cast here:
http://www.richardlawrence.info/2009/12/03/screencast-testing-web-applications-in-net-with-cuke4nuke-and-watin/

I think they're quite similar, so watching the screencast should get you the basic idea.

(You can also checkout Cuke4nuke's wiki)

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble in getting started, why don't you switch to a framework that has a tutorial available?
I have written a complete run-through for my own BDD engine, called Aubergine; you can see it here:
http://www.corebvba.be/blog/post/Getting-started-quickly-with-BDD-in-Net.aspx