# how should I think to ensure good BDD design?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, bdd, karma-runner

I am new to BDD and I get some understanding on it via online articles. I am thinking to do BDD for my new AngularJS app. I am still quite use with the old method, when start on a project, thinking on function and create it step by step.

So, how can I get myself comfortable & think in BDD when developing? How can I ensure I am writing good BDD test that will have good coverage of all my code?

Comment: See also [BDD-related topics on Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bdd?sort=votes&pageSize=15) site which is designed for non-coding questions about software requirements, development methodologies and processes etc. This one seems to cover your question: [Programmers: Is BDD scalable for medium to large projects?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/188228/129832)

Answer (score 1):

There are [different flavors of BDD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524511). In my opinion the strengths of BDD is to define the requirements collaboratively. Thus, I prefer the name *Specification by Example (SbE)* instead of *Behavior Driven Development (BDD)*, as it indicates that this technique can be used to ask the right questions and to work out the details together with different stakeholders. When you want to start with SbE, it helps if you change your viewpoint and look at your problem / project from the customer and user view. After defining the happy path you can dig deeper with your team and define the edge cases.

Please, be aware that SbE is not a silver bullet. I would recommend that to use "usual" unit tests as basis for your test coverage and use SbE as add-on to drive your development based on customer requirements. From the technical perspective you should take care that you [write specifications, not scripts](http://concordion.org/Technique.html).

Answer (score 0):

As with most things, it depends. What I do for BDD is to think of the interactions the user will have and map out the key flows and functionality. For a front-end application, I think of how the user will interact with the application (clicking on a navigation menu, signing up for an account, etc) and then write my tests along those behaviors. BDD is more of a paradigm than any specific implementation and I have seen it done differently in different projects. However, what it boils down to is considering the behaviors the application will demonstrate given a specific state and testing it to minimize regressions or breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Think about

WHAT you are doing

and

WHY are you doing it (e.g. what value does it have)

get those clear before you think about HOW you are going to do something. This is the key to BDD, before you can Drive anything you have to understand the Behaviour and be able to express it clearly.