# What is RSpec and Cucumber

Tags: rspec, specflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rspec vs cucumber (rspec stories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393622/rspec-vs-cucumber-rspec-stories)

```
 watz the difference between them
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From different wiki pages we see that:

- RSpec is a behavior driven development (BDD) framework for the Ruby programming language, inspired by JBehave
- Cucumber is a tool that executes plain-text functional descriptions as automated tests

So you can think of Cucumber as the tool that translate plain text into executable tests. These test can be written in for example RSpec.

But RSpec can also be used on it's own where it's a BDD framework in it own right. The specifications are then expressed not in plain english but in Ruby code.