# Alternatives to pending Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am looking for a way to keep a specific feature test within my codebase to use later but I don't want cucumber to run it for now because it is slowing down my running of the tests. Is there a way that i can do this?

Comment: Have you checked out [RSpec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306760/cucumber-vs-rspec)?

Comment: Yes I am very familiar with rspec. I am just looking for an alternative way to keep my test pending.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you mark a Cucumber Scenario as Pending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064078/how-do-you-mark-a-cucumber-scenario-as-pending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [tag](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) the test with something like `@slow` and then omit it when you execute cucumber. That would look something like this:

```
cucumber --tags ~@slow
```

Later, when perhaps you want to execute only that test, you can do:

```
cucumber --tags @slow
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add the @wip (work in progress) tag before the scenario you want to skip.

```
Feature: Doing stuff
  @wip
  Scenario: Some Sweet Tests
    Given...
```