# Should Cucumber use the RSpec features folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, cucumber, bdd

First off, I understand this is a total newb question, but I'm just a little confused about this one thing:

When I installed RSpec, a folder was created in `./spec/features`. Then when I installed cucumber, a folder was created in `./features`. I was wondering if I should configure cucumber to use the rspec features folder and if so how? Or should I delete the rspec features folder? Or am I not clear about something and each folder is used for something different?

I realize this is probably a matter of opinion, but I'm just wondering what the popular best practice is. Any tips?

Comment: There is much debate on whether to even use cucumber in most cases. I tend to favour rspec and capybara (capybara integration specs would go in the `/spec/features` dir). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393622/rspec-vs-cucumber-rspec-stories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete the rspec features folder. You won't need it if you use rspec for testing your models and controllers, and cucumber for your integration tests

Comment: that advice is why there's much debate. Use Cucumber if you have pro-active customers who want to help write the high-level tests. Most of those tests will hit the raw Ruby code, the same way RSpec tests do. SOME FEW tests should use Capybara to test integration, and SOME FEW of those could also use Cucumber.

Comment: @Phlip - I don't think Dylan was questioning whether to use Cucumber at all. His question was just about the folders being used. Let's not turn this question into a Cucumber versus Capybara or RSpec discussion!

Comment: Sry just channeling DHH C-;